# post data to CouchDB "docker container"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, couchdb, svelte, pouchdb

I have built an image for "bitnami/couchdb" in digitalocean and the docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  couchdb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/couchdb:3
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=admin
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - '5984:5984'
    volumes:
      - couchdb_data:/bitnami/couchdb
volumes:
  couchdb_data:
```

and I'm using PouchDB with svelte to sync the data and the code and image work fine locally
but  in digitalocean does not work and posting the data to the CouchDB

and the connection works locally with

```
http://admin:password@localhost:5984/twd3
```

but with the IP did not work

```
http://admin:password@179.58.192.33:5984/twd3
```

and I did enable the cors.

Comment: Is the db accessible with something like curl?

Comment: I have tried ```curl -X GET http://179.58.192.33:5984:5984/_all_dbs``` and it works

Comment: Actually, everything works fine, post fetch put and delete, I have no idea what was the problem.
Thanks...

Comment: In order get maybe useful error messages, please use [pouchdb-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-debug) in your svelte frontend. It helped me a lot in the past. If you have, useful error messages (in the browser console), please post them here.